# How to buffer efficiently when writing to 1000s of files in C++

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, io, output-buffering

I am quite inexperienced when it comes to C++ I/O operations especially when dealing with buffers etc. so please bear with me.

I have a programme that has a vector of objects (1000s - 10,000s). At each time-step the state of the objects is updated. I want to have the functionality to log a complete state time history for each of these objects.

Currently I have a function that loops through my vector of objects, updates the state, and then calls a logging function which opens the file (ascii) for that object, writes the state to file, and closes the file (using std::ofstream). The problem is this **signficantly** slows down my  run time.

I've been recommended a couple things to do to help speed this up:

1. Buffer my output to prevent extensive I/O calls to the disk
2. Write to binary not ascii files

My question mainly concerns 1. Specifically, how would I actually implement this? Would each object effectively require it's own buffer? or would this be a single buffer that somehow knows which file to send each bit of data? If the latter, what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with just not opening and closing your file every time you want to log. See where it takes you. You may need to change the open file limit to keep 1000s of files open at the same time.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? How large is "the state" for each object separately? For the whole system? Are you allowed to batch writes? Are you allowed to log the state of the world in one file instead of thousands? Are you allowed to separate computation and output into different threads?

Comment: Try to avoid opening and closing files constantly. Open the file for each object and leave it open. See how much performance you get from that.

Comment: @Botje Sure - the state of each object occupies a 288 byte string - this is the same for all objects. In theory I could put the state of everything into one file but would have to do some type of post processing step to separate them later. Threading is potentially an option. Could you clarify what you mean by a batch write?

Comment: Only write the files every N iterations, this corresponds to your "buffering idea"

Comment: At each iteration, which part (%age) of the objects are being actually updated? You might want to write only those on-disk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest idea first: instead of logging to separate files, why not log everything to an [SQLite database](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)?

Given the following table structure:

```
create table iterations (
    id integer not null,
    iteration integer not null,
    value text not null
);
```

At the start of the program, prepare a statement once:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v3(db, "insert into iterations values(?,?,?)", -1, SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT, &stmt, NULL);
```

The question marks here are placeholders for future values.

After every iteration of your simulation, you could walk your state vector and execute the `stmt` a number of times to actually insert rows into the database, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    // Fill in the three placeholders and execute the query.
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, current_iteration); // Could be done once, but here for illustration.
    std::string state = objects[i].get_state();
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, state.c_str(), state.size(), SQLITE_STATIC); // SQLITE_STATIC means "no need to free this"
    sqlite3_step(stmt); // Execute the query.
}
```

You can then easily query the history of each individual object using the SQLite command-line tool or any database manager that understands SQLite.